# Update null table values with value from previous record

Tags: vba, ms-access

There's a table named sample, and it has two columns id, and id2. Some records on id2 are filled with numbers, but some are null. So I need to fill them up with the same number as their closest record. That is, if each record on id2 is not null, move on to the next one, and if each record on id2 is null, fill it in with the previous one. How can I do this with vba?

sample

```
id    id2
1     100
2     
3     500
4     600
5     
6     800
```

sample_result

```
id    id2
1     100
2     100
3     500
4     600
5     600
6     800
```

Comment: Why VBA, why not an UPDATE query?

Comment: Can it be possible with just UPDATE query?

Answer (score 1):

In Access I'm not sure it can be done in pure SQL, but I think this should get you close to what you want:

```
UPDATE sample AS s
SET    s.id2 = Dmax("id2", "sample", "id <" & [s].[id])
WHERE  (( ( s.id2 ) IS NULL ));
```